# Plot many csv "row" files in Matlab (or R if you prefere)

Tags: r, matlab, csv, plot

## Problem

I have 50 .csv files with this structure:

```
value1,value2,...
```

One single long line with each value separated by a comma.

Specifically they are floating point numbers and each csv has a different number of values.

```
0.0023593,0.0062565,0.00723753,0.0023353,0.0052353,0.0024353,...
```

I have to plot each data file in the *same* graph, to find the trend of this values and possibly with an average plot.

**How can I do this in a simple manner? Matlab is preferred but R is ok**

### Update

I know I can do something like [in Matlab]:

```
>> arr1 = csvread('file1.csv');
>> plot(arr1)
```

and

```
>> arr2 = csvread('file2.csv');
>> plot(arr2)
```

...but I'm looking for a procedural way.

### Update2

Thanks for the answers, I've done a simple hack and I end up with the correct solution, but it is a hack. I've just used python to replicate the commands and then I runned all them...

@Crowley your solution could be right but unfortunately there are some syntax problems.

@njc thanks for your effort! but this is not what I needed, maybe my result can help you to develop R code, then I will surely promote your answer as the correct one.

Here the result:

[image]

Made with this "stupid" [script](http://pastebin.com/9BG94t27)

Comment: How are the files names and are they in the same folder? Getting the data into the program is probably the crucial thing here, right?

Comment: the names are sudoku1_EUC.csv sudoku2_EUC.csv ... sudoku50_EUC.csv . The problem is that I have almost zero knoledge of these two framework.

Comment: It sounds like a basic looping task of reading the files and then producing some nice graphs with facets of legends accounting for various files. Could you consider making example more reproducible by providing some content resembling your real data for a couple of files?

Comment: why not show us what you tried and pick one language

Comment: Ok , sudoku0_EUC.csv : http://pastebin.com/FfBCryCM 
sudoku1_EUC.csv : http://pastebin.com/1J6KXg2N 
sudoku15_EUC.csv : http://pastebin.com/LBFRw7gS
@rawr because I told you I have zero knoledge of the framework. I've noticed that you can do a single call to collect a csv into an array, but I don't want to do it by hand. I'm asking a procedural way which I don't know.

Comment: I've thought that I could append to a single file each row of all the csv files and let Matlab consider the first row an array then the second row another array so on so forth...until the 50th row. So I will end up with a huge matrix in matlab. Then I want to plot each row as a graph. Could be this a solution? And how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid I don't know any MATLAB, but one way to do this in R is to use the ggplot2 package. It works by adding different layers to the plot, which makes it a convenient way to use different data frames.

First I generated some example data to use.

```
a <- data.frame(runif(100))
b <- data.frame(runif(150))
c <- data.frame(runif(125))

names(a) <- 'y'
names(b) <- 'y'
names(c) <- 'y'
```

These are just data frames of random variables that are different lengths. Because all your data seem to be one dimensional, I made a box plot.

Then I create a ggplot using each data frame separately.

```
p <- ggplot()
p <- p + geom_boxplot(data=a, aes(y=y, x=1, color='a'))
p <- p + geom_boxplot(data=b, aes(y=y, x=2, color='b'))
p <- p + geom_boxplot(data=c, aes(y=y, x=3, color='c'))
p         # to show the plot
```

Each time I use geom_boxplot() I'm adding another layer to the plot. You can also do this in one line.

```
p <- ggplot() + geom_boxplot(data=a, aes(y=y, x=1, color='a')) + geom_boxplot(data=b, aes(y=y, x=2, color='b')) + geom_boxplot(data=c, aes(y=y, x=3, color='c'))
p         # to show the plot
```

[image: Simple box plot. It's also easy to do things like change the axis names, legend title, etc.]

Now that I'm reading your post again, it occurs to me that you might mean that you want to point these as scatter plots, with the position of the number in the file as the x value. That's easy to do with ggplot, though in my example you won't see any trend because my values are all random.

```
q <- ggplot()
q <- q + geom_point(data=a, aes(y=y, x=1:dim(a)[1], color='a'))
q <- q + geom_point(data=b, aes(y=y, x=1:dim(b)[1], color='b'))
q <- q + geom_point(data=c, aes(y=y, x=1:dim(c)[1], color='c'))
q
```

Or

```
q <- ggplot() + geom_point(data=a, aes(y=y, x=1:dim(a)[1], color='a')) + geom_point(data=b, aes(y=y, x=1:dim(b)[1], color='b')) + geom_point(data=c, aes(y=y, x=1:dim(c)[1], color='c'))
q
```

[image: Scatter plot]

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions about ggplot; I'll do my best though I'm certainly not an expert.

Note: I changed the column names of a, b, and c to 'y' before making the plots, but I forgot to update their names when making the data.

Is the only difference between this and what you want the smoothed curve instead of the points? If so, that's an easy fix.

First I changed the data so that it would have a trend.

```
a <- data.frame(runif(100)-(1:100)/300)
b <- data.frame(runif(150)-(1:150)/300)
c <- data.frame(runif(125)-(1:125)/300)
names(a) <- 'y'
names(b) <- 'y'
names(c) <- 'y'
```

Then I simply replaced `geom_point` with `geom_smooth`.

```
r <- ggplot()
r <- r + geom_smooth(data=a, aes(y=y, x=1:dim(a)[1], color='a'), se=FALSE)
r <- r + geom_smooth(data=b, aes(y=y, x=1:dim(b)[1], color='b'), se=FALSE)
r <- r + geom_smooth(data=c, aes(y=y, x=1:dim(c)[1], color='c'), se=FALSE)
r
```

[image: Plot with geom_smooth]

The `se=FALSE` stops it from displaying the standard error as a gray band in the background. If the standard error is helpful to you, you can just omit it.

Comment: @rawr I've got ggplot 2.0.0 loaded. Looks like they're up to 2.1.0 now.

Comment: your edit fixed it, thanks

Comment: @rawr Might be that I named the columns 'a', 'b', and 'c'.  Let me know whether it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Say we have data in `YourFolder='whatever\address\'` folder, then if we want `double` array:

```
Files=dir(['YourFolder' .*']);  % look for csv. files in the folder
[M,~]=size(Files);           % count them
AllData=zeros(M,0);

for ii=1:M
  Temp=importdata([YourFolder,Files(ii).name '.csv'],','); % Read csv file into a structure
  Temp=Temp.data;   & Use only the data part
  if size(Temp,2>size(AllData,2)  %compare 2. dimensions of AllData and Temp
    % if Temp is wider, then append NaN values to AllData to match widths
    n=size(Temp,2)-size(AllData,2);
    Refill=nan(M,n);
    AllData=[AllData,Refill];
  elseif size(Temp,2<size(AllData,2)
    % If AllData is wider then append NaN values to Temp to match widths
    n=size(AllData,2)-size(Temp,2);
    Refill=nan(1,n);
    Temp=[Temp,Refill];
  end
  % append new line to AllData
  AllData(ii,:)=Temp;
end

plot(AllData') % Alldata shall be transposed because plot uses columns as data sets by default.
```

If we want `cell` array to work with the code is simpler, since vectors doesn't need to match.

```
Files=dir(['YourFolder' .*']);  % look for csv. files in the folder
[M,~]=size(Files);           % count them
AllData=cell(M,1);

for ii=1:M
  Temp=importdata([YourFolder,Files(ii).name '.csv'],','); % Read csv file into a structure
  Temp=Temp.data;   & Use only the data part

  % append new line to AllData
  AllData{ii}=Temp;
end

plot(AllData(:))
```